# Is there a function or method to suspend the main thread for a specified amount of time?

Tags: qt, sleep, thread-sleep

Is there a wrapper function for `Sleep` / `usleep` in Qt that can be used in the main thread, or do I have to write my own wrapper? It's not a lot of code, but would be a shame to write my own if there already is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variant 1:

Pro-file:

```
CONFIG += qtestlib
```

Code:

```
#include <QTest>

QTest::qSleep( 10000 ); // 10 sec
```

Variant 2:

```
#ifndef XSLEEP_H 
#define XSLEEP_H 

#include <QThread> 

class Xsleep : public QThread 
{ 
public: 
    static void msleep(int ms) 
    { 
        QThread::msleep(ms); 
    } 
}; 

#endif  

C++:
while (true) 
{ 
        ... 
        Xsleep::msleep(1000); // 1 sek 
        ... 

}
```